# Thread blocks itself from sending intent by waiting on intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am currently writing some code that sends an intent to an outside application and waits for a response using "sendOrderedBroadcast()" and condition variables. While doing this I manage to block the intent from being sent out while attempting to wait on the response from the outside application.

My code looks something like this:

```
final ConditionVariable cond = new ConditionVariable();
BroadcastReceiver responseReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        //set data values here
        cond.open();
    }
};
sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null, responseReceiver , null, 0, null, null);
cond.block(TIMEOUT);
```

The scenario is that when the application triggers this section of code at a rate of 2-3 times per second the sendOrderedBroadcast does not actually send the intent before the block() method is called (or at least this is my current theory). This means that the intent is not received by the receiving application until after the timeout completes.

Is there an easy way to get around this? I have tried using different methods of waiting on this intent to be returned (Sleeping, busy waiting, countdown latches, separate threads, etc) but I have consistently run into the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `sendOrderedBroadcast()`, the broadcast is not performed immediately, nor is it performed by the same thread that made the call. A broadcast `Intent` is sent by the android framework itself. Basically, you are making an asynchronous call and asking the Android framework to send the ordered broadcast for you. The framework will not be able to sent the broadcast until you give control back to it (ie: `return` from your method). You don't give control back to the framework, you block immediately.

Also, you absolutely positively cannot block the main (UI) thread under any circumstances. You haven't indicated where you call `cond.block()`, but this had better be in a background thread and not in the main thread. In general, you shouldn't be blocking anything anyway. You should just do nothing and wait for the callback (or whatever) and continue processing when the callback comes.

Comment: To start, I would like to clarify that this is not being done by the UI thread. The entire program is a service running in the background. 

Just to make sure that I understand the response, you are saying that should I call the sendOrderedBroadcast in it's own separate method then I should be able to resolve the issue? Just so long as I wait on the response in the encasing method?

I ask because I attempted to follow those steps, and I am still able to regularly reproduce the issue and I want to know if I missed something.

Comment: What do you mean by "a service running in the background". Do you start background threads in your `Service`? A `Service` doesn't, by default, run in the background. Secondly you misunderstood. You cannot wait on the response in the same method. You must return from the method. The broadcast will then come at some later time.

Comment: Also, be aware that `onReceive()` on your `responseReceiver` will be called on the main (UI) thread.